# How do I calculate the molecular mass of a complex in a complexometric titration with EDTA?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, titration, elemental-analysis

I had to titrate 0.35 mmol (3.2 g) of $\ce{Co2F2(Hdmpz)6(BF4)2}$ in a solution with 10 drops of 37 % $\ce{HCl}$, 10 mL of 4 M $\ce{NaOAc}$, 25 mL water and xylenol orange as indicator with  a 0.05 M EDTA solution.

Now I'm supposed to calculate the percentage $\ce{Co^2+}$ and then calculate the molecular weight of the whole complex.

Let's just say I saw color change at 16 mL EDTA. How do I calculate the percentage and the molecular weight? I'm also not sure about the molar ration $\ce{Co^2+}$:$\ce{EDTA}$.

If I just count the atoms it should be about 906 g/mol.

Comment: The stoichiometric ratio is 1:1. It forms a $\ce{[Co(edta)]^2-}$ complex.

Comment: I also thought the stoichiometric ratio was 1:1, but my teacher said it was wrong. But she didn't explain me why.

Comment: You titrated $0.7\mathrm{~mmol}$ of $\ce{Co^2+}$ with EDTA and you reached the endpoint at $(0.05\mathrm{~M})(16\mathrm{~ml}) = 0.8\mathrm{~mmol}$ of EDTA, so I don't see why it's not 1:1. I am guessing you might have added just a bit too much EDTA, especially if it is your first time doing an EDTA titration (I know I did so).

Comment: Yes, I have most likely used too much EDTA, and my 3,2 g wasn't measured perfectly.  So it is 1:1, I don't understand my teacher.